# Validating email for a specific username using php and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

So, I am trying to validate whether username and email entered by a user in an html form are correct according to Database

I have a database called testing and a table called info which has two fields:
 name and email.

this is the code

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="conn.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>   
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>


    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="testing";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mail=$_POST['email'];
// Create connection
$conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query='select email from info where name= "$name"';
$results = mysqli_query($conn1,$query);
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
echo $row["email"];
$email=$row["email"];
if($mail==$email){
    echo " correct values";
} 
else 
    echo " incorrect";
//echo $name, $email;
// Check connection
//if ($conn1->connect_error) {
//    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
//} 
//echo "Connected successfully";
$conn1->close();
?>
```

but the result is always incorrect. The values that i enter in the text boxes match the values in the database.

Comment: First: Don't try to interpolate user-input directly into sql queries, use placeholders ('?'), youre open to SQL-Injection attacks otherwise. If you had used placeholders, the query would actually have worked -- as your code stands you select for a literal '$name' as name, NOT the entered name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use placeholders, the code would be something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT emal FROM info WHERE name = ?';
$stmt  = mysqli_stmt_prepare($conn1, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

For better readable code, read up on the object-oriented mysqli-interface, or better yet use PDO.

Answer (score -1):

alternatively you can use string concatenation like

Update this line

```
$query='select email from info where name= "$name"';
```

with

```
$query='select email from info where name= "'.$name.'" ';
```

or with

```
$query="select email from info where name= '".$name."' ";
```